# Stop CSS transitions from running on page load

Tags: html, css

EDIT: added own answer and it works.
if anyone can improve it, that will be great!

Is there any way to stop CSS transitions from playing/running in the background?
Consider there is a CSS animation the the bottom of the page, but it loads right after the page is loaded, but we are not yet scrolled to the bottom of the page. So the CSS animation was never seen!
It would be nice to be able to prevent or trigger animations/transitions on page load without JavaScript.
I dont want to repeat the animation on every time user scrolls the page or on hover. The animation should wait until the user scrolls and the section is visible in the screen.

I tried the following, but it didn't work!

HTML

```
<body class="preload">
```

CSS

```
.preload * {
  -webkit-transition: none !important;
  -moz-transition: none !important;
  -ms-transition: none !important;
  -o-transition: none !important;
}
```

Javascript

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $("body").removeClass("preload");
});
```

It would be nice to be able to prevent or trigger animations/transitions on page load without JavaScript.
Here is the website [link](http://shijilt8.sg-host.com/mobile-phones/samsung-galaxy-m21-6gb-price-202886.html). There are 6 rings with animation when scrolled almost 25%.

Comment: I think to use CSS only can't be possible because CSS can't have onload event

Comment: If you use **animation property** instead of *transitions*. use `animation-play-state: paused; ` to pause animation if you wan't to start by `running` [more info](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-play-state.asp)

Comment: this can be done using a scroll event

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible without javascript, however, you can use a library of your choice for such animations (like [this one](https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/%5D(this%20one))) or you can implement a custom solution.

For custom solution, you'll use `Intersection Observer API` to detect when an element has been scrolled into view and then you'll add your animation class onto that element.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, I changed this:

old CSS

```
.preload * {
      -webkit-transition: none !important;
      -moz-transition: none !important;
      -ms-transition: none !important;
      -o-transition: none !important;
    }
```

new CSS

```
.preload {
  transition: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Can you comment the line where the change was made so its easy to understand the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following codes and it works very well, see the result [link](http://shijilt8.sg-host.com/mobile-phones/samsung-galaxy-m21-6gb-price-202886.html)

added animation function in this CSS

```
.divname .is-visible {
    animation: progress 2s ease-out forwards;
}
```

and `.divname` with other normal CSS functions.
so the javascript calls the .is-visible CSS and enable animation each time.

```
// Detect request animation frame
var scroll = window.requestAnimationFrame ||
             // IE Fallback
             function(callback){ window.setTimeout(callback, 1000/60)};
var elementsToShow = document.querySelectorAll('.show-on-scroll'); 

function loop() {

  elementsToShow.forEach(function (element) {
    if (isElementInViewport(element)) {
      element.classList.add('is-visible');
    } else {
      element.classList.remove('is-visible');
    }
  });

  scroll(loop);
}

// Call the loop for the first time
loop();

// Helper function from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7557433/274826
function isElementInViewport(el) {
  // special bonus for those using jQuery
  if (typeof jQuery === "function" && el instanceof jQuery) {
    el = el[0];
  }
  var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  return (
    (rect.top <= 0
      && rect.bottom >= 0)
    ||
    (rect.bottom >= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
      rect.top <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight))
    ||
    (rect.top >= 0 &&
      rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight))
  );
}
```